Molecular Docking
I have been docking multiple ligands on a protein,the ligands were correct initially (without explicit hydrogen ATOMS all ligands were processed by same method) but some ligand poses show additional hydrogen atom in the ligand output whereas some ligands did not show explicit hydrogen atoms.
I also tried using two docking platforms autodock vina as well as QVina.
I have uploaded the ligand output one with no issue and other with explicit hydrogens.

We received additional hydrogen along with ligands as you can see in second image and before docking the ligand is normal (image 1). So here is what we perform firstly we optimize the ligand structure using RDKit and apply the MMFF (Merck Molecular Force Field) for energy minimization. Subsequently, perform molecular docking using QVina to produce this output.
Why did this happen and how do I solve this?

Why is this question tagged with chimera?

plz provide solution

I don't know enough about the problem to be able to provide a good solution. I'm trying to help you improve your question, so that someone who does know about this domain can give a better answer.

please provide at least two ligannds and describe the procedure that gave out two different kind of results

cant you just feed the algho with ligand already contining explicit Hs provided by third party procedure ??
